# Is it possible to shoot tethered to a Linux laptop?

Tags: tethering, linux

I have never tried shooting tethered, but I would like to give it a try.

My laptop uses Ubuntu linux.

Can you point me at any solutions for tethering this to my camera?
I have a Canon 5DmkII, but to make this question more useful to others, please give any solutions you know of which work with other cameras too.

Many thanks,

Comment: I don't think it should be migrated, but you might try this over at http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only option I can see, right now, is using gPhoto for this but since I primarily use Linux in a server role, I might be missing some. Anyways, there's a pretty good tutorial on using gPhoto this way available here: [Linux.com](http://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/47498-sophisticated-picture-taking-with-gphoto) and that might do the trick for you.

Comment: gPhoto works really well. I use it fairly often. It is not as user friendly as I would like it (only comand line) but it does the job.

Comment: +1 for using gphoto; there's also a guide to making timelapse videos with it at http://www.moreno.marzolla.name/software/time_lapse_movies/

Answer (score 6):

This is a native software you could use:

http://entangle-photo.org/

*Edit:*

And this too:
http://www.darktable.org/

Answer (score 3):

You can use VirtualBox ([www.virtualbox.org](http://www.virtualbox.org/)), free software from Sun/Oracle, to create an MS Windows virtual machine that runs under Linux. Inside the virtual machine you can install and run the camera specific tethering software.

I have used this method to run the MS Windows specific software for my Garmin Forerunner GPS watch and to control a large, high speed Canon scanner, all from my Ubuntu Linux machine.

Two points to note
1. Under settings, remember to enable the USB 2.0 controller
2. In the virtual machine, select Devices | Usb Devices and select the USB camera device so that it is made available to MS Windows in the virtual machine.